# Angular service worker doesn't cache assets once deployed on Github pages (sub-directory)

Tags: angular, github-pages, angular-service-worker, angular-cli-v9

I developed an Angular PWA demo application (Angular v9.1.3), implementing `performance` and `freshness` strategies.

**Locally it works perfectly, even offline.** But once deployed on Github pages, it is not working anymore as expected:

1. `performance` strategy keeps fetching all Requests from the network, not from the cache
2. Once offline, the app doesn't work, as nothing seems to be cached

I use `angular-cli-ghpages` to deploy to gh-pages with the following command (angular-pwa-boilerplate is the Repo name):

```
    ng deploy --base-href=/angular-pwa-boilerplate/
```

Once deployed, I adjust the `start_url` property of the web-manifest file to "/angular-pwa-boilerplate/" to reflect the subdirectory structure.

**Even though the scope path seems being correct and the app is installable, the service worker does not caches the assets nor the Http Responses (while locally all is fine).**

I read many articles about it, but all the fixes did not work:

1. Use a relative path `./` for the service worker file: 
   `ServiceWorkerModule.register('./ngsw-worker.js', ...)`
2. Set relative values for scope and start_url in manifest file:
   "scope": ".", 
   "start_url":" "./"

Here the [DEMO](https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/) and [Github Repo](https://github.com/pacoita/angular-pwa-boilerplate/tree/gh-pages)

It seems also that there is still [some ongoing work](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/31082) on this topic.

---

**UPDATE**

I noticed that if I leave `start_url: "/"` (hence without adjusting it to the base-href), Angular Service Worker and its caching strategies work like a charm also on gh-pages.

However the app is no more installable:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you see if you access the [debug info](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#locating-and-analyzing-debugging-information):

```
NGSW Debug Info:

Driver state: EXISTING_CLIENTS_ONLY (Degraded due to: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/manifest.webmanifest: expected cbcd3fc3623610507d05fab49a40b0fcb22f47bb, got 69c8bc4c8eb903528013fe49ac2c8a521b120901 (after cache busting)
Error: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/manifest.webmanifest: expected cbcd3fc3623610507d05fab49a40b0fcb22f47bb, got 69c8bc4c8eb903528013fe49ac2c8a521b120901 (after cache busting)
    at PrefetchAssetGroup.<anonymous> (https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/ngsw-worker.js:734:35)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/ngsw-worker.js:174:62))
Latest manifest hash: 4f36c4b0eb2e39ccabb57986bc3191e39cabad0c
Last update check: 1m45s215u

=== Version 4f36c4b0eb2e39ccabb57986bc3191e39cabad0c ===

Clients: 

=== Idle Task Queue ===
Last update tick: 1m50s390u
Last update run: 1m45s381u
Task queue:


Debug log:

[2m40s282u] Ignoring invalid request: 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode Driver.fetch(https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/, cache: only-if-cached, mode: no-cors)
[2m34s503u] Error(Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/manifest.webmanifest: expected cbcd3fc3623610507d05fab49a40b0fcb22f47bb, got 69c8bc4c8eb903528013fe49ac2c8a521b120901 (after cache busting), Error: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/manifest.webmanifest: expected cbcd3fc3623610507d05fab49a40b0fcb22f47bb, got 69c8bc4c8eb903528013fe49ac2c8a521b120901 (after cache busting)
    at PrefetchAssetGroup.<anonymous> (https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/ngsw-worker.js:734:35)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/ngsw-worker.js:174:62)) initializeFully for 4f36c4b0eb2e39ccabb57986bc3191e39cabad0c
[2m6s104u] TypeError(Failed to fetch, TypeError: Failed to fetch) Driver.fetch(https://pacoita.github.io/angular-pwa-boilerplate/)
```

<sub>NOTE:
The debug info is normally available as `/ngsw/state`, but this does not work when serving from a sub-path. This will be fixed with [angular/angular#31082](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/31082). I just hacked my way to the debug info.</sub>

Based on the debug info, it seems that there is a hash mismatch for the `manifest.webmanifest`, which causes the ServiceWorker to not work properly. This means that the contents of the file that is served to the browser is different than the content of the file when the `ngsw.json` file was generated (during `ng build`). This is because you are modifying the file after being built.

In order to avoid this you should modify the source file before building (and let the changes propagate to the built artifacts.

Have you also tried using `--baseHref` option of [ng build](https://angular.io/cli/build) (i.e. `ng build --prod --baseHref=/angular-pwa-boilerplate/ ...`)? This should take care of updating any URLs (including `manigest.webmanifest`) automatically.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. I am looking forward for the incoming fix :)
I was using `angular-cli-ghpages` for the deploy, but it does not update the start_url field yet. I will create a PR for that.

Comment: ng build with --base-href option updates only the index.html, but not the start_url property of web manifest. I filed an issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15092 that got fixed by using a relative path "./", but no other change is applied.

Comment: Oh, that sounds like a bug. Can you open an issue on https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/new (or better yet submit a pull requet with the fix ;)?

Comment: I already filed an issue (see previous comment), that was closed with this PR: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/17075.

Comment: Oh, then `./` should work. Why do you mention `start_url: "/"` (instead of `start_url: "./"`) in your question?

Comment: I did not have it in my Project. This fix has been introduced in Angular 9.1.2 and the project had been created before, so it still had the "old" version -> "/" and it did not work. My mistake was to edit it by hand after the deploy.

Comment: Cool! So, editing it before the deploy should make things work for you, right?

Comment: Absolutely. I could solve it by correcting it before deploying it. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction